# What is the percentage of true bugs compared to all animal species on the plant?

Tags: entomology, taxonomy

Also, what is the percentage of True Bugs compared to the insect population?

I’m writing a children’s book on bugs and I’m comparing the true bug to the insect. All population info seems to combine the two. Please list sources.

Comment: Wellcome to Biology SE. Please could you explain what you mean by "bug" and "true bug". I'm no entomologist so I can only go on my Chambers dictionary, which defines bug as "a name loosely applied to certain insects…and specific to one (Cimex lectularis) that infests houses and beds". Is this what you mean? But it has nothing to do with plants. Or do you mean "on the planet"? Unless you clarify your question, I'm afraid you are not going to get the answer you are after.

Comment: @David I think "True Bugs" are usually defined as [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera). Also, that article lists an estimate of 50,000 - 80,000 species of hemiptera. If you find estimates for total insect species and total animal species, you could get your own estimated percentages for each.

Comment: @user137 — Many thanks for providing this information. I'm sure many others besides myself will have been enlightened.